# In powershell, is it possible to convert such string "name:eric,city:tokyo" into json?

Tags: json, powershell

I'm using powershell and I have a string like `"name:eric,city:tokyo"`, is it possible to convert it into json like below:

```
{
"name":"eric",
"city":"Tokyo"
}
```

I tried with `convertto-json` cmdlet, but could find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way would be to parse the properties from the string, convert to some custom object type, then pass this object to [`ConverTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7). Using `"name:eric,city:tokyo" | ConvertTo-Json` is not recommended, since it won't know how to evaluate the string into JSON. It also won't give back valid JSON, which is not what your after. There are some ways below on how you could do this instead.

**Method 1:**

Insert the items manually into an `ordered` hashtable object then pipe to `ConverTo-Json`:

```
$s = "name:eric,city:tokyo"

$items = [ordered]@{}

$s.Split(",") | ForEach-Object {
    $key, $value = $_.Split(":")
    $items[$key] = $value
}

$items | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Method 2:**

Use a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0), similar to **Method 1**:

```
$s = "name:eric,city:tokyo"

$psobject = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

$s.Split(",") | ForEach-Object {
    $key, $value = $_.Split(":")
    $psobject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $key -NotePropertyValue $value
}

$psobject | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Method 3**

Instead of storing your data in a string to begin with, have your data preset in a [`PSCustomObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscustomobject?view=pscore-6.2.0) or an `ordered` hashtable. Then the conversion is easy.

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    name = "eric"
    city = "tokyo"
} | ConvertTo-Json

[ordered]@{
    name = "eric"
    city = "tokyo"
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

All of which will result in:

```
{
  "name": "eric",
  "city": "tokyo"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. All works well but the first solution does not generate a real json(when I use convertfrom-json, then try to use .name, it does not work ).

Comment: @IvanYang Your right. I've removed the first solution. Its not valid JSON, since the strings need to be quoted.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information, it really helps me a lot.

Comment: @IvanYang No worries, glad the information helped :)